# LUIS website hangs up at initializing

Tags: nlp, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am working with LUIS NLP service provided through website www.luis.ai. I am not able to open this website for few days, it hangs right on the account login page with message - "Please wait a few moments... Initializing". Is there some issue in LUIS or I am missing something? I have attached the image where this site hangs.

Any help will be appreciable. Thanks.

[image: This image shows LUIS website in hanging state]

Comment: FYI, I am using updated chrome browser.

Comment: Try using IE or Edge. That's what I do whenever the site get stuck on the loading.

Comment: MS should seriously look into fixing the LUIS site. It's too buggy and many a times I've had to refresh the browser or clear the cache to make it workable! Duh!

Answer (score 1):

We're also seeing this issue, quite a lot. There site is quite buggy on the front-end.

What has worked for us was to use IE, it seems to run a bit better there. Also, if it gets stuck on 'initializing' for like 3 or 4 seconds, a refresh usually does the trick

Comment: Hi @JPThome, thanks for your quick response. we are not able to open this at all for couple of days. Neither on chrome, Version 56.0.2924 nor Internet Explorer Version, 11.0.9600. Could you please let us know your IE version?

Comment: Hi @SuryaSingh seems like I am on the same version of IE as you, so that's not it then. 

You might try a cache refresh for example, and I suppose you could F12 in and check the devtools for any errors. 

Other than that, if you're able to log a support request with them via that little support button they are quite good about getting back to you. Although if the site never loads then you might be stuck on that one. Some googling might reveal their support email. 

You could try logging an issue on their github repo, but there isn't much activity there.